# ReactJS - use context of parent state in it's child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little problem. I want to set state of my parent using a props callback in my child. Situation looks similar to this:

PARENT COMPONENT

```
(...)
onOptionsChange(newState){
        this.setState(newState);
    }
render(){
    return (
        <Options onOptionsChange={(newState) => 
        this.onOptionsChange(newState)} />
        )
}
}
(...)
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
(...)
switch(option.target.id) {
          case 'facebook': 
                this.props.onOptionsChange({...this.state,
                options:{...this.state.options,
                facebook: option.target.checked}})
(...)
```

...but the final context is always my child context, so the app crashes. Is there any possibility to move context from child to parent? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you will have a state in the parent component that you will pass on to the child and then the child uses it from the props and if it wants to make any change it will update the parent state

Try it like

ParentComponent

```
(...)
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data : {// some state, option : {//values here}, facebook: false}
    }
}
...
onOptionsChange(newState){
        this.setState({data: newState});
    }
render(){
    return (
        <Options onOptionsChange={(newState) => 
        this.onOptionsChange(newState)} data = {this.state.data}/>
        )
}
}
(...)
```

ChildComponent

```
(...)
switch(option.target.id) {
          case 'facebook': 
                this.props.onOptionsChange({...this.props.data,
                options:{...this.props.options,
                facebook: option.target.checked}})
(...)
```